# How to view IndexedDB content in firefox

Tags: firefox, indexeddb

I've been playing with IndexedDB in Firefox (Ubuntu)

Is there any way to visualize IndexedDB databases contents ?
Or do I have to do it programmatic-ally  ?

Answer (score 20):

Bleeding edge Chromium builds reportedly allow you to view IndexedDB content in the Resources panel of the Chrome devtools, but only I know of one way to view Firefox IndexedDB content non-programmically and that's to load the .sqlite file directly.

Firefox's IndexedDB .sqlite files are located at `/Users/{USER}/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/{PROFILE}/indexedDB` on OS X and should be `C:\Users\{USER}\AppData\Roaming\Mozilla\Firefox\Profiles\{PROFILE}` on Windows.

I use the excellent (and free) Firefox tool [SQLite Manager](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/sqlite-manager/), which is cross platform.

[image: which looks like this]

One thing to keep in mind however is that the contents are often stored as binary blobs and are likely not to be human readable. Keys are stored as text however so they should be able to be read by hand.

**Update** Although local files remain a great way to view IDB databases and stores, Chrome does now have great tooling available in the Resources panel.

Comment: will take a look at chromium... Everybody keep saying indexedDB is the future. Right now I find myself hunting butterflies with a fork in a dark room. Anyway, thanks for your answer.

Comment: Just set up a user group. Feel free to email non-straightforward questions and I'll try to answer. http://groups.google.com/group/indexeddb-users?msg=new&lnk=gcis

Comment: SqlLite Manager is awesome. Thanks for the tip. Yea, it shows values as blobs but at least I see all the objectstores, keys, etc.

Comment: Fernando, One master trick that we had to develop for IndexedDB is to wait till all transaction ended before starting any schema changes, like adding new ObjectStore, adding index to the existing store, etc. If you like, you can check the sources indexedDB.js and taskQueue.js in http://github.com/urbien/urbini 

For that we used [jquery-indexeddb.js](http://nparashuram.com/jquery-indexeddb/) to put IDB requests into taskQueue as promises. Then we had to fallback to Chrome's file api, as Chrome does not support blobs. Also, we used [IDB shim](http://nparashuram.com/IndexedDBShim/) for Safari...

Comment: I am trying but  I don't see indexeddb file:///users/{user}/Library/Application Support/Firefox/Profiles/5kaqoz4x.default/ the indexeddb tutorial (simple to-do) and indexeddb should have key pair values

Comment: Firefox now has this capabilitie, just open dev tools and go to storage.

Answer (score 9):

I just downloaded the IndexedDB Browser add-on for Firefox. It works well. Once downloaded it is located in:

Tools > Web Developer > IndexedDB Browser

https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/indexeddb-browserupdated-fix/

EDIT:
Since Firefox 26 the files for IndexedDB have moved from

```
{PROFILE}/indexedDB/
```

to

```
{PROFILE}/storage/persistent/
```

The current Version (0.1.4) does not handle this change. However it can be easily solved with a symbolic link.

Comment: Since this addon hasn't been updated, someone made an tweaked version that works: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/indexeddb-browserupdated-fix/

Comment: It's been a while, but thanks @JW. I updated the link.

Answer (score 5):

In the new versions of firefox, the developer tools comes with a handy Storage Inspector.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector

Currently you have to use the nightly build of firefox to get it

https://nightly.mozilla.org/

EDIT: Storage Inspector is now in main build

Comment: This is currently the easiest/best answer (though it's in the main build now).

Answer (score 3):

Firefox indexedDB location on Ubuntu is:

`~/.mozilla/firefox/*.default/storage/persistent/`

or

`~/.mozilla/firefox-trunk/*.default/storage/persistent/`

Comment: For Pale Moon: `~/home/retro/.moonchild productions/pale moon/*.default/`

Answer (score 2):

You can try my indexeddbviewer, it is located on http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com.

The following things you'll need to do:
- Add the following references to your page:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-1.7.2.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/Linq2IndexedDB.js"> </script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../Scripts/IndexedDBViewer.js"> </script>
```

This means you need to get jQuery + jQuery UI
And linq2indexedDB (this is my lib and you can get it also on http://linq2indexeddb.codeplex.com).

And to make it work add the following in the body:

```
<body>
    <p><label id="lblDatabaseName" for="txtDatabaseName">Database name:</label> <input type="text" id="txtDatabaseName" /><input type="button" id="btnViewDatabase" value="View database" /></p>
    <div id="tabs">
        <ul>
        </ul>
    </div>
</body>
```

I'll tye to work out an easier way asap.

An other way is just use my linq2indexeddb library, and create an new instance of it like this:

```
var db = window.linq2indexedDB("Database name", null, true)
```

if you have done this you can call an attribute viewer, that will give you all the information about the indexeddb database.

```
db.viewer
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
let db;
function createDB() {    
    let dbName = "Jokes";
    let dbVersion = 5;
    let request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
    request.onupgradeneeded = e => {
      db = e.target.result
      console.log(db);
      let jstore = db.createObjectStore("JokeStore", {keyPath: "title"});
      let mstore = db.createObjectStore("MockStore", {keyPath: "title"});
      alert("upgrade");
    }
    request.onsuccess = e => {
      db = e.target.result
      console.log(db);
      alert("success");
    }
    request.onerror = e => {
      alert("error"+e.target.error);
    }
}
function addRecord(title, text) {
    let tx = db.transaction("JokeStore","readwrite");
    tx.onerror = e => alert(e.target.error);
    let jstoretx = tx.objectStore("JokeStore");
    jstoretx.add({title: title, text: text});
}
function viewNotes() {
  let tx = db.transaction("JokeStore", "readonly");
  let jstore = tx.objectStore("JokeStore");
  let request = jstore.openCursor();
  request.onsuccess = e => {
    let cursor = e.target.result;
    if (cursor) {
      console.log(cursor.key, cursor.value.text);
      cursor.continue();
    }
  }
}
createDB(); // Creates db if not there or opens an existing one
addRecord("Joke 1", "Knock Knock"); // Adds record
addRecord("Joke 2", "Elephant and the ant"); // Adds record
viewNotes(); // Displays all records in console
```

Answer (score 0):

I had to read the indexedDB from a WhatsApp Web session, and I did it this way:

```
function readDB() {
    let dbName = "wawc";
    let dbVersion = 70;
    let request = indexedDB.open(dbName, dbVersion);
    request.onsuccess = e => {
      let db = e.target.result
      let tx = db.transaction("user", "readonly");
      let jstore = tx.objectStore("user");
      let request = jstore.openCursor();
      request.onsuccess = e => {
        let cursor = e.target.result;
        if (cursor) {
          console.log(cursor.key, cursor.value);
          cursor.continue();
        }
      }
    }
    request.onerror = e => {
      console.log("error"+e.target.error);
    }
}
readDB();
```

Console log will show the contents of table 'user' in 'wawc' database.