# Why can't I connect to my SQLite database using indexedDB.open?

Tags: sqlite, indexeddb

I have a database of Sqlite. I want to connect to my file by indexedDB. 
Also I tried indexedDB, it created new sqlite file in profile. This new sqlite file has a table with the name of "database". This table contain of name of my file.

My source code is:

```
var indexedDB = window.indexedDB 
    || window.webkitIndexedDB 
    || window.mozIndexedDB
    || window.msIndexedDB;

var db;
var request = indexedDB.open("rule");
request.onerror = function(evt) {
  console.log("Database error code: " + evt.target.errorCode);
};
request.onsuccess = function(evt) {
  console.log("Database connect success");
  db = request.result;
};
```

When the code runs, the `db` variable is empty.

Comment: never tried it, but I don't think that is possible to the way you want. As far I know you can only create an indexeddb database by using the open with version method and initiating the structure in js code.

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible.

While [Firefox stores its own IndexedDB databases in an SQLite format](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878154/317937), you cannot query or access these databases directly. Instead, you need to use the asynchronous IDB API.

Comment: Thanks for your help, but i connect to myself database in firefox browser. IDB API did'nt help me...

Comment: No... :( can i use the Storage API?

Comment: @samira, I don't think you understand how StackOverflow works. Just because the answer is not the one you're looking for doesn't mean that it's not correct. And when you have a different question than the one you asked, you post a new question.

Answer (score 0):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you have a pre-existing SQLite database and you are trying to connect to it using IndexedDB?

As editor said in his answer, this is **not possible**. [IndexedDB](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/IndexedDB/Basic_Concepts_Behind_IndexedDB) is not a generic interface for accessing databases. The name is kind of deceptive, *IndexedDB is not a relational database*; it actually allows you to create [Object Stores](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Persistent_object_store) in the browser to store JavaScript objects in. These stores are created in the browser using JavaScript, the current implementation in Firefox does store IndexedDB data in a SQLite database but [the spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/IndexedDB/) does not require this, each browser may store the data however they like behind the scenes. Other browsers, and future versions of Firefox may or may not use SQLite at all, again that doesn't really matter because IndexedDB does not provide access to the backend databases it uses anyway. Even the current implementation in Firefox does not solely rely on SQLite, it stores things like `File` and `Blob` objects [separate from the SQLite DB](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/07/why-no-filesystem-api-in-firefox/).