# Is it possible in IndexedDB to specify the database store directory?

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I was wondering, if we can store data in a specific location when using IndexedDB? or it can only be decided by the browser?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The user cannot determine the storage location of raw IDB storage files. You likely would not want to - this location [varies widely across operating system](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9878154/317937) and even browser "profile." Managing this "sandbox" is a core browser operation.

Comment: Now that I think of it, it makes sense. Thanks.

Comment: Indeed! Let me know if I can help further. Otherwise we always appreciate a "correct" answer in the IDB tag stream :)